# XMLHttpRequest - difference between Chrome & Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am seeing intermittent aborts of POST XMLHttpRequests in Firefox.

In FF DevTools Network the request line has a grey status circle & has no status number. The response tab is empty. In Firebug the status shows as aborted and I read somewhere this means the call was aborted by the browser (would mean server not an issue?).

- Began about the time Firefox 46 became the production version (April 26).
- Users do not experience these failures in Chrome.
- Users are located around the world (not a local issue).
- The requests being aborted seem to be random, occurs in less than 1% of requests.
- No other request is active or made when the failure happens.
- I have not noticed any GET failures.

Does anyone know of any differences between Chrome & Firefox handling of XMLHttpRequests that could cause something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug introduced in Firefox 46.

Should be fixed in version 47 being released on June 7th

Answer (score 0):

> [Adjust your server side persistent connection timeout to be about 5 seconds longer than the firefox value. Firefox uses 115 seconds for HTTP/1.x and 180 seconds for HTTP/2.](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/post-request-fails-on-certain-sites-showing-connection-reset-page/)